# Ruby on Rails ayuda con modelos, namespace y reaciones many-to-many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespace

Tengo problemas manejando los *namespace*, tengo los siguientes modelos:

```
class Administradora::Owner < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :owner_mails, foreign_key: :administradora_owner_id
  has_many :junta_mails, through: :owner_mails
end

class Junta::Mail < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :owner_mails, class_name: "OwnerMail", foreign_key: :junta_mail_id
  has_many :adminstradora_owners, through: :owner_mails
end

class OwnerMail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :administradora_owner, foreign_key: :owner_id, primary_key: :administradora_owner_id
  belongs_to :junta_mail, foreign_key: :mail_id, primary_key: :mail_id
end
```

Por consola puedo hacer lo siguiente:

```
Administradora::Owner.first.owner_mails
Junta::Mail.find(4).owner_mails
```

Funciona bien, pero si intento:

```
x = OwnerMail.create(administradora_owner_id: 4,junta_mail_id: 3, created_at: "2016/04/04", updated_at: "2016/04/04")
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Los id `4` y `3` existen en sus respectivas tablas y el error es:

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Administradora owner
>   must exist, Junta mail must exist

No sé que puede estar pasando.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios puntos que pueden ocasionar el comportamiento que describes:

1. Tal como lo resalta [yorodm](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/28656/yorodm) en su [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/81930/42433), es necesario utilizar `class_name` para especificar la clase cuando los modelos están en *namespaces* distintos (puedes ver más información, en inglés, [aquí](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)).
2. Verifica que los nombres de los `id` en tus tablas sean los correctos; por ejemplo, si estás siguiendo los estándares de rails, `administradora_owner_id` debería ser simplemente `owner_id` (esto lo puedes verificar en tus migraciones).
3. Solo necesitas especificar `foreign_key` / `primary_key` para las columnas de `id` que no sigan los estándares de rails, de lo contrario puedes omitirlas; pero en cualquier caso debes ser consistente.

   Por ejemplo en `Junta::Mail` tienes:

   ```
   has_many :owner_mails, class_name: "OwnerMail", foreign_key: :junta_mail_id
   ```

   Mientras que en `OwnerMail` tienes:

   ```
   belongs_to :junta_mail, foreign_key: :mail_id, primary_key: :mail_id
   ```

   Ambas se refieren al `id` de `Junta::Mail`, pero con diferente columna.

Considerando lo anterior, tus modelos podrían modificarse para verse así<sup>1</sup>:

```
class Administradora::Owner < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :owner_mails
  has_many :mails, through: :owner_mails
end

class Junta::Mail < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :owner_mails
  has_many :owners, through: :owner_mails
end

class OwnerMail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, class: "Administradora::Owner"
  belongs_to :mail, class: "Junta::Mail"
end
```

<sup>1</sup> *Asumo que las columnas de `id` de `Administradora::Owner` y `Junta::Mail` son `owner_id` y `mail_id` respectivamente (es decir, siguen los estándares de rails); en caso que no sea así, agrega las `foreign_key` de cada tabla.*

Comment: Gracias por responder Gerry,

Hice lo que indicaste y me sigue dando el error parecido:

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Owner must exist, Mail must exist

No lo mencione pero los modelos no están en modules, administradora es un directorio al igual que junta. 
En la tabla owner_mails tengo: id, administradora_owner_id y junta_mail_id, 
Genere un modelo usando reference para generar las claves foráneas:
rails g model OwnerMail administradora_owner:references junta_mail:references

Pero me sigue dando mostrando el problema

Comment: @josedes ¿Podrías actualizar (editar) tu pregunta agregando las migraciones de los tres modelos?

Comment: @josedes No es necesario que pongas `_administradora` o `_junta` como prefijos en tus llaves, con utilizar `owner:references` y `mail:references` es suficiente (y las relaciones funcionarían tal como están en la respuesta).

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente no sea exactamente la solución que quieres pero siempre que uso modelos en distintos módulos utilizo la opción `class_name` para crear relaciones. Quedaría así:

```
belongs_to ... :class_name => 'Administradora::Owner'
```

Comment: Gracias yorodm, lo coloque y me sigue dando el mismo problema, los modelos no están en modulos solo en directorios, administradora y owner, no entiendo  por que sale ese error

Comment: @josedes El *loader* de Rails no se comporta exactamente como el de Ruby estándar. Por ejemplo `Administradora::Owner` tiene que estar en en `app/models/administradora/owner.rb`. ¿Tienes la estructura de archivos así?

Comment: Es correcto la tengo así,

Comment: De echo pude resolverlo de la siguiente manera:

Answer (score 0):

De hecho pude resolverlo de la siguiente manera:

```
class Administradora::Owner < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :owner_mails, foreign_key: :administradora_owner_id, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :junta_mails, through: :owner_mails
  :administradora_owner_id
end

class Junta::Mail < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :owner_mails, foreign_key: :junta_mail_id, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :administradora_owners, through: :owner_mails
end

class OwnerMail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :administradora_owner,  class_name: "Administradora::Owner", foreign_key: :administradora_owner_id
  belongs_to :junta_mail,  class_name: "Junta::Mail", foreign_key: :junta_mail_id
end
```

Ya puedo crear y puedo buscar en la join table a través de los modelos de `Administradora::Owner` y `Junta::mail`